# How to change the coordinate system without losing the data points in the new transformed plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, coordinate-systems, rnaturalearth

I have a `dataframe`, called `coords` which contains `x` and `y` coordinates. (Please see below to get the output of `dput(coords)` for reproducibility.

I add a column containing a random value for each pair of coordinates:

```
# load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(dplyr)

df = coords |> 
        mutate(value = runif(length(coords$x), 0, 100))
```

Then, I get the coastlines data as a `sf` class:

```
# get the coastline data as sf
coastlines_sf = ne_coastline(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
```

I can plot my data inside of the coastlines data using `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot() +
        geom_tile(data = df, mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +
        scale_fill_viridis_c() +
        geom_sf(data = coastlines_sf)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Now, I want to change the coordinate system, e.g. using:

```
ggplot() +
        geom_tile(data = df, mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +
        scale_fill_viridis_c() +
        geom_sf(data = coastlines_sf) +
        coord_sf(crs = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ")
```

[image]

As we can see, my does not show up here. How can I make sure that my data also show up in the new plot?

**Reproducible output of dput(coords)**:

```
> dput(coords)
structure(list(x = c(101.5, 102.5, 105.5, 106.5, -114.5, 100.5, 
101.5, 102.5, 103.5, 104.5, 105.5, 106.5, 107.5, 108.5, 109.5, 
90.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 94.5, 105.5, 106.5, 107.5, 108.5, 109.5, 
90.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 94.5, 105.5, 106.5, -114.5, -112.5, -111.5, 
-109.5, -106.5, -105.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 90.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 
94.5, 105.5, 106.5, 107.5, 108.5, 109.5, -114.5, -113.5, -112.5, 
-111.5, -110.5, -109.5, -108.5, -107.5, -106.5, -105.5, -79.5, 
-78.5, -77.5, 80.5, 81.5, 84.5, 90.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 94.5, 
105.5, 106.5, 107.5, 108.5, 109.5, -154.5, -152.5, -114.5, -113.5, 
-112.5, -111.5, -110.5, -109.5, -108.5, -107.5, -106.5, -105.5, 
-79.5, -78.5, -77.5, -76.5, -75.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 
90.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 94.5, 105.5, 106.5, 107.5, 108.5, 109.5, 
-154.5, -153.5, -152.5, -151.5, -150.5, -113.5, -112.5, -111.5, 
-110.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 29.5, 
70.5, 71.5, 74.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 86.5, 87.5, 
88.5, 89.5, 120.5, 121.5, 122.5, 123.5, 124.5, 135.5, 136.5, 
137.5, 138.5, 139.5, 145.5, 146.5, 147.5, 148.5, 149.5, -179.5, 
-154.5, -153.5, -152.5, -151.5, -150.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 
29.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 70.5, 71.5, 72.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 
84.5, 85.5, 86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 89.5, 120.5, 121.5, 122.5, 123.5, 
124.5, 135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 138.5, 139.5, 145.5, 146.5, 147.5, 
148.5, 149.5, -179.5, -178.5, -177.5, -176.5, -175.5, -154.5, 
-153.5, -152.5, -151.5, -150.5, -114.5, -111.5, -110.5, -104.5, 
-103.5, -102.5, -100.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 29.5, 35.5, 36.5, 
37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 70.5, 71.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 
86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 89.5, 120.5, 121.5, 122.5, 123.5, 124.5, 135.5, 
136.5, 137.5, 138.5, 139.5, 145.5, 146.5, 147.5, 148.5, 149.5, 
-179.5, -178.5, -177.5, -176.5, -175.5, -154.5, -153.5, -152.5, 
-151.5, -150.5, -114.5, -113.5, -112.5, -111.5, -110.5, -104.5, 
-103.5, -102.5, -101.5, -100.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 29.5, 
37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 70.5, 71.5, 73.5, 74.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 
84.5, 85.5, 86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 89.5, 120.5, 121.5, 122.5, 123.5, 
124.5, 135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 138.5, 139.5, 145.5, 146.5, 147.5, 
148.5, 149.5, -175.5, -154.5, -153.5, -152.5, -151.5, -150.5, 
-114.5, -113.5, -112.5, -111.5, -110.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, 
-101.5, -100.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 29.5, 70.5, 71.5, 72.5, 
73.5, 74.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 
89.5, 120.5, 121.5, 122.5, 123.5, 124.5, 135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 
138.5, 139.5, 145.5, 146.5, 147.5, 148.5, 149.5, -160.5, -159.5, 
-158.5, -157.5, -156.5, -155.5, -139.5, -138.5, -137.5, -136.5, 
-135.5, -128.5, -127.5, -126.5, -125.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, 
-101.5, -100.5, 20.5, 50.5, 51.5, 52.5, 53.5, 54.5, 90.5, 91.5, 
92.5, 93.5, 94.5, 110.5, 111.5, 112.5, 113.5, 114.5, 125.5, 126.5, 
127.5, 128.5, 129.5, 130.5, 131.5, 132.5, 133.5, 134.5, 165.5, 
166.5, 167.5, 168.5, 169.5, -160.5, -159.5, -158.5, -157.5, -156.5, 
-155.5, -139.5, -138.5, -137.5, -136.5, -135.5, -129.5, -128.5, 
-126.5, -125.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, -101.5, -100.5, 23.5, 
24.5, 50.5, 51.5, 52.5, 53.5, 54.5, 90.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 94.5, 
110.5, 111.5, 112.5, 113.5, 114.5, 125.5, 126.5, 127.5, 128.5, 
129.5, 130.5, 131.5, 132.5, 133.5, 134.5, 165.5, 166.5, 167.5, 
168.5, 169.5, -164.5, -163.5, -162.5, -161.5, -160.5, -159.5, 
-158.5, -157.5, -156.5, -155.5, -139.5, -138.5, -137.5, -136.5, 
-135.5, -129.5, -128.5, -125.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, -101.5, 
-100.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 50.5, 51.5, 52.5, 53.5, 54.5, 
90.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 94.5, 110.5, 111.5, 112.5, 113.5, 114.5, 
125.5, 126.5, 127.5, 128.5, 129.5, 130.5, 131.5, 132.5, 133.5, 
134.5, 165.5, 166.5, 167.5, 168.5, 169.5, -164.5, -163.5, -162.5, 
-161.5, -160.5, -159.5, -158.5, -157.5, -156.5, -155.5, -137.5, 
-136.5, -135.5, -129.5, -128.5, -125.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, 
-101.5, -100.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 50.5, 51.5, 52.5, 53.5, 54.5, 
90.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 94.5, 110.5, 111.5, 112.5, 113.5, 114.5, 
125.5, 126.5, 127.5, 128.5, 129.5, 130.5, 131.5, 132.5, 133.5, 
134.5, 165.5, 166.5, 167.5, 168.5, 169.5, -164.5, -163.5, -162.5, 
-161.5, -160.5, -159.5, -158.5, -157.5, -156.5, -155.5, -135.5, 
-129.5, -128.5, -127.5, -126.5, -125.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, 
-101.5, -100.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 50.5, 51.5, 52.5, 53.5, 54.5, 
90.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 94.5, 110.5, 111.5, 112.5, 113.5, 114.5, 
125.5, 126.5, 127.5, 128.5, 129.5, 130.5, 131.5, 132.5, 133.5, 
134.5, 165.5, 166.5, -132.5, -131.5, -130.5, -129.5, -128.5, 
-127.5, -126.5, -125.5, -124.5, -123.5, -122.5, -121.5, -120.5, 
-119.5, -118.5, -117.5, -116.5, -115.5, -108.5, -107.5, -106.5, 
-105.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, -101.5, -100.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 
13.5, 14.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 
89.5, -131.5, -130.5, -129.5, -128.5, -127.5, -126.5, -123.5, 
-122.5, -121.5, -120.5, -119.5, -118.5, -117.5, -116.5, -115.5, 
-109.5, -108.5, -107.5, -106.5, -105.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, 
-101.5, -100.5, 11.5, 12.5, 14.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 
85.5, 86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 89.5, -128.5, -127.5, -123.5, -122.5, 
-121.5, -120.5, -119.5, -118.5, -117.5, -116.5, -115.5, -109.5, 
-108.5, -107.5, -106.5, -105.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, -101.5, 
-100.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 
86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 89.5, -128.5, -127.5, -126.5, -125.5, -123.5, 
-122.5, -121.5, -120.5, -119.5, -118.5, -117.5, -116.5, -115.5, 
-109.5, -108.5, -107.5, -106.5, -105.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, 
-101.5, -100.5, 13.5, 14.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 
86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 89.5, -126.5, -124.5, -122.5, -121.5, -120.5, 
-119.5, -118.5, -117.5, -116.5, -115.5, -109.5, -108.5, -107.5, 
-106.5, -105.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, -101.5, -100.5, 80.5, 
81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 89.5, -126.5, 
-125.5, -64.5, -63.5, -62.5, -61.5, -60.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 
33.5, 34.5, 95.5, 96.5, 97.5, 98.5, 99.5, 105.5, 106.5, 107.5, 
108.5, 115.5, 116.5, 117.5, 118.5, 119.5, -126.5, -125.5, -64.5, 
-63.5, -62.5, -61.5, -60.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 95.5, 
96.5, 97.5, 98.5, 99.5, 105.5, 106.5, 107.5, 109.5, 115.5, 116.5, 
117.5, 118.5, 119.5, -128.5, -125.5, -64.5, -63.5, -62.5, -61.5, 
-60.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 95.5, 96.5, 97.5, 98.5, 
99.5, 105.5, 106.5, 108.5, 109.5, 115.5, 116.5, 117.5, 118.5, 
119.5, -64.5, -63.5, -62.5, -61.5, -60.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 
34.5, 95.5, 96.5, 97.5, 98.5, 99.5, 105.5, 106.5, 107.5, 108.5, 
109.5, 115.5, 116.5, 117.5, 118.5, 119.5, -63.5, -62.5, -61.5, 
-60.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 95.5, 96.5, 97.5, 98.5, 99.5, 
105.5, 106.5, 107.5, 108.5, 109.5, 115.5, 116.5, 117.5, 118.5, 
119.5, -99.5, -98.5, -97.5, -96.5, -95.5, -69.5, -68.5, -57.5, 
-56.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 55.5, 56.5, 57.5, 58.5, 
59.5, 75.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 79.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 
91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 95.5, 96.5, 97.5, 98.5, 99.5, 130.5, 131.5, 
132.5, 133.5, 134.5, 135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 138.5, 139.5, -99.5, 
-98.5, -97.5, -96.5, -95.5, -69.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -57.5, 
-56.5, -55.5, 10.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 55.5, 56.5, 57.5, 58.5, 
59.5, 75.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 79.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 90.5, 
95.5, 96.5, 97.5, 98.5, 99.5, 130.5, 131.5, 132.5, 133.5, 134.5, 
135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 138.5, 139.5, -99.5, -98.5, -97.5, -96.5, 
-95.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -55.5, 10.5, 14.5, 
55.5, 56.5, 57.5, 58.5, 75.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 79.5, 80.5, 81.5, 
82.5, 83.5, 91.5, 97.5, 98.5, 99.5, 130.5, 131.5, 132.5, 133.5, 
134.5, 135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 138.5, -99.5, -98.5, -97.5, -96.5, 
-95.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, 14.5, 55.5, 56.5, 57.5, 
58.5, 59.5, 78.5, 79.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 96.5, 97.5, 98.5, 
99.5, 130.5, 131.5, 132.5, 133.5, 134.5, 135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 
-99.5, -98.5, -97.5, -96.5, -95.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, 
10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 56.5, 57.5, 78.5, 79.5, 80.5, 81.5, 
82.5, 83.5, 130.5, 131.5, 132.5, 133.5, 134.5, 135.5, 136.5, 
-119.5, -118.5, -117.5, -116.5, -115.5, -74.5, -73.5, -72.5, 
-71.5, -70.5, -64.5, 5.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.5, 
44.5, 65.5, 115.5, 116.5, 117.5, 118.5, 119.5, 142.5, -119.5, 
-118.5, -117.5, -116.5, -115.5, -74.5, -73.5, -72.5, -71.5, -70.5, 
5.5, 6.5, 43.5, 44.5, 65.5, 66.5, 115.5, 116.5, 117.5, 118.5, 
119.5, 142.5, 143.5, 144.5, -119.5, -118.5, -117.5, -116.5, -115.5, 
-74.5, -73.5, -72.5, 69.5, 115.5, 116.5, 117.5, 118.5, 119.5, 
140.5, 142.5, -119.5, -118.5, -117.5, -116.5, -115.5, -74.5, 
42.5, 43.5, 44.5, 67.5, 68.5, 108.5, 109.5, 115.5, 116.5, 117.5, 
118.5, 119.5, -119.5, -118.5, -117.5, -116.5, -115.5, 40.5, 41.5, 
42.5, 43.5, 44.5, 66.5, 67.5, 68.5, 69.5, 115.5, 116.5, 117.5, 
118.5, 119.5, 140.5, 141.5, -99.5, -98.5, -97.5, -96.5, -95.5, 
20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 140.5, 141.5, -99.5, -98.5, -97.5, -96.5, -95.5, 
21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 140.5, -99.5, -98.5, -97.5, -96.5, -95.5, 22.5, 
140.5, -99.5, -98.5, -97.5, -96.5, -95.5, 140.5, -99.5, -98.5, 
-97.5, -96.5, -95.5, 88.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, -104.5, -103.5, 
-102.5, -101.5, -100.5, -79.5, -78.5, -77.5, -104.5, -103.5, 
-102.5, -101.5, -100.5, -79.5, 44.5, -104.5, -103.5, -102.5, 
-101.5, -100.5, 44.5, 120.5, -104.5, -103.5, -101.5, -100.5, 
-104.5, -103.5, -102.5, -101.5, -100.5, -90.5, 108.5, 109.5, 
82.5, 108.5, 109.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 108.5, 109.5, 82.5, 
83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 89.5, 105.5, 108.5, 109.5, 
80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 89.5, 105.5, 
106.5, 107.5, 108.5, 109.5, 79.5, 75.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 79.5, 
75.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 79.5, 75.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 79.5, 75.5, 
76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 79.5, -16.5, -15.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, 
-5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 9.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 75.5, 76.5, 
77.5, 78.5, 79.5, -15.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 
8.5, 9.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 75.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 
79.5, -15.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 
9.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 75.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 79.5, 
-9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 35.5, 
36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 79.5, -69.5, -68.5, 
-9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 35.5, 
36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 50.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 79.5, -83.5, 
0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 29.5, 30.5, 
31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.5, 44.5, -82.5, 
-81.5, -80.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 
29.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.5, 44.5, 
80.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 29.5, 
30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.5, 44.5, 80.5, 
81.5, 0.5, 1.5, 4.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 29.5, 30.5, 31.5, 
32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.5, 44.5, 80.5, 81.5, 25.5, 
26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 29.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 40.5, 41.5, 
42.5, 43.5, 44.5, -54.5, -53.5, -52.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 
24.5, 45.5, 46.5, 47.5, 96.5, 97.5, -54.5, -53.5, -52.5, -51.5, 
20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 45.5, 46.5, 97.5, 98.5, -54.5, 
-53.5, -52.5, -51.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 45.5, 98.5, 
99.5, -54.5, -53.5, -52.5, -51.5, -50.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 
24.5, 99.5, -54.5, -53.5, -52.5, -51.5, -50.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 
23.5, 24.5, 99.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 100.5, 101.5, 
102.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 101.5, 102.5, 103.5, -44.5, 
20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 101.5, 102.5, 103.5, 104.5, 137.5, 
138.5, 139.5, -44.5, -43.5, -42.5, -41.5, -40.5, 20.5, 21.5, 
22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 102.5, 103.5, 104.5, 136.5, 137.5, 138.5, 139.5, 
-44.5, -43.5, -42.5, -41.5, -40.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 
103.5, 104.5, 136.5, 137.5, 138.5, 139.5, -44.5, -43.5, -42.5, 
-41.5, -40.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 
33.5, 34.5, 145.5, -44.5, -43.5, -42.5, -41.5, -40.5, 20.5, 21.5, 
22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 145.5, 146.5, 
-44.5, -43.5, -42.5, -41.5, -40.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 
31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 145.5, 146.5, -44.5, -43.5, -42.5, -41.5, 
-40.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 
34.5, 146.5, 147.5, -44.5, -43.5, -42.5, -41.5, -40.5, 20.5, 
21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 147.5, 
148.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 
30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 142.5, 
30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 131.5, 
132.5, 133.5, 134.5, 135.5, 142.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 
35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 130.5, 131.5, 132.5, 133.5, 134.5, 
135.5, 142.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 
38.5, 39.5, 130.5, 131.5, 132.5, 133.5, 134.5, 135.5, 142.5, 
143.5, -72.5, -71.5, -70.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 35.5, 
36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 35.5, 36.5, 
37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 35.5, 36.5, 44.5, 
15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 35.5, 36.5, 44.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 
18.5, 19.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 
138.5, 139.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 
138.5, 139.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 
138.5, 139.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 
138.5, 139.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 135.5, 136.5, 137.5, 
138.5, 139.5, 120.5, 121.5, 122.5, 123.5, 124.5, 135.5, 136.5, 
137.5, 138.5, 139.5, 120.5, 121.5, 122.5, 123.5, 124.5, 135.5, 
136.5, 139.5, 120.5, 121.5, 122.5, 123.5, 124.5, 135.5, 139.5, 
120.5, 121.5, 122.5, 123.5, 124.5, 135.5, 120.5, 121.5, 122.5, 
123.5, 124.5, 136.5, 138.5, 139.5, 30.5, 145.5, 146.5, 147.5, 
148.5, 149.5, 173.5, 145.5, 146.5, 147.5, 148.5, 149.5, 146.5, 
147.5, 148.5, 149.5, 146.5, 174.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -69.5, 
-68.5, -67.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, 
-69.5, -68.5, -69.5, -69.5, -69.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5), y = c(76.5, 
76.5, 76.5, 76.5, 75.5, 75.5, 75.5, 75.5, 75.5, 75.5, 75.5, 75.5, 
75.5, 75.5, 75.5, 74.5, 74.5, 74.5, 74.5, 74.5, 74.5, 74.5, 74.5, 
74.5, 74.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 72.5, 72.5, 
72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 
72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 
71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 
71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 70.5, 
70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 
70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 
70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 69.5, 69.5, 
69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 
69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 
69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 
69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 68.5, 
68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 
68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 
68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 
68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 
66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 
66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 
66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 
66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 
66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 65.5, 65.5, 
65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 
65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 
65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 
65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 
65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 65.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 
64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 
64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 
64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 
64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 
64.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 
63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 
63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 
63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 
63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 63.5, 62.5, 62.5, 
62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 
62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 
62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 
62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 
62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 
61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 
61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 
61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 
61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 
61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 60.5, 
60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 
60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 
60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 
60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 
60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 
59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 
59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 
59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 
59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 
58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 
58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 
58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 57.5, 57.5, 
57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 
57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 
57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 56.5, 
56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 
56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 
56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 
56.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 
55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 
55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 54.5, 54.5, 
54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 
54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 
54.5, 54.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 
53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 
53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 
52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 
52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 51.5, 
51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 
51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 
51.5, 51.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 
50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 
50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 
49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 
49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 
49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 
49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 
48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 
48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 
48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 
48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 
47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 
47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 
47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 
47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 
46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 
46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 
46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 
45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 
45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 
44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 
44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 
44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 
43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 
43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 
42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 
42.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 
41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 
40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 
40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 
39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 
38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 
36.5, 36.5, 36.5, 36.5, 36.5, 36.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 
35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 
34.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 
32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 31.5, 31.5, 31.5, 31.5, 30.5, 30.5, 30.5, 
30.5, 30.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 28.5, 28.5, 28.5, 27.5, 27.5, 27.5, 
27.5, 27.5, 27.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 
26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 
25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 24.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 
23.5, 23.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 
21.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 
14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 
14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 
13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 
13.5, 13.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 
12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 
12.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 
11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 9.5, 9.5, 
9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 
9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 
8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 
8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 
7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 
6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 
6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 
4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 
3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 
2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 
-0.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -2.5, -2.5, 
-2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5, 
-3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -3.5, 
-3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -3.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, 
-4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, 
-5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, 
-5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, 
-6.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, -6.5, 
-7.5, -7.5, -7.5, -7.5, -7.5, -7.5, -7.5, -7.5, -7.5, -7.5, -7.5, 
-7.5, -7.5, -7.5, -7.5, -7.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, 
-8.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5, 
-9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -9.5, 
-9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -9.5, -10.5, -10.5, -10.5, -10.5, 
-10.5, -10.5, -10.5, -10.5, -10.5, -11.5, -11.5, -11.5, -11.5, 
-11.5, -11.5, -11.5, -11.5, -11.5, -11.5, -12.5, -12.5, -12.5, 
-12.5, -12.5, -12.5, -12.5, -12.5, -12.5, -12.5, -12.5, -12.5, 
-12.5, -12.5, -12.5, -13.5, -13.5, -13.5, -13.5, -13.5, -13.5, 
-13.5, -13.5, -13.5, -13.5, -13.5, -13.5, -13.5, -13.5, -13.5, 
-13.5, -13.5, -14.5, -14.5, -14.5, -14.5, -14.5, -14.5, -14.5, 
-14.5, -14.5, -14.5, -14.5, -14.5, -14.5, -14.5, -14.5, -14.5, 
-14.5, -14.5, -15.5, -15.5, -15.5, -15.5, -15.5, -15.5, -15.5, 
-15.5, -15.5, -15.5, -15.5, -15.5, -15.5, -16.5, -16.5, -16.5, 
-16.5, -16.5, -16.5, -16.5, -16.5, -16.5, -16.5, -17.5, -17.5, 
-17.5, -17.5, -17.5, -17.5, -17.5, -17.5, -18.5, -18.5, -18.5, 
-18.5, -18.5, -18.5, -18.5, -18.5, -19.5, -19.5, -19.5, -19.5, 
-19.5, -20.5, -20.5, -20.5, -20.5, -20.5, -20.5, -20.5, -20.5, 
-20.5, -20.5, -21.5, -21.5, -21.5, -21.5, -21.5, -21.5, -21.5, 
-21.5, -21.5, -21.5, -22.5, -22.5, -22.5, -22.5, -22.5, -22.5, 
-22.5, -22.5, -22.5, -22.5, -23.5, -23.5, -23.5, -23.5, -23.5, 
-23.5, -23.5, -23.5, -23.5, -23.5, -24.5, -24.5, -24.5, -24.5, 
-24.5, -24.5, -24.5, -24.5, -24.5, -24.5, -25.5, -25.5, -25.5, 
-25.5, -25.5, -25.5, -25.5, -25.5, -25.5, -25.5, -26.5, -26.5, 
-26.5, -26.5, -26.5, -26.5, -26.5, -26.5, -27.5, -27.5, -27.5, 
-27.5, -27.5, -27.5, -27.5, -28.5, -28.5, -28.5, -28.5, -28.5, 
-28.5, -29.5, -29.5, -29.5, -29.5, -29.5, -29.5, -29.5, -29.5, 
-30.5, -35.5, -35.5, -35.5, -35.5, -35.5, -35.5, -36.5, -36.5, 
-36.5, -36.5, -36.5, -37.5, -37.5, -37.5, -37.5, -38.5, -39.5, 
-45.5, -45.5, -45.5, -46.5, -46.5, -46.5, -47.5, -47.5, -47.5, 
-47.5, -48.5, -48.5, -48.5, -49.5, -49.5, -50.5, -51.5, -52.5, 
-53.5, -53.5, -54.5)), row.names = c(NA, -2010L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Likely foolish thinking, but not `df2 <-  st_transform(coords, 'laea' ` prior to  second plot?, as it appears that `+coords_sf(` is only 'reaching back' to coastline for transform, here assuming `something +` in ggplot notation is akin to somthing() |> or %>%, and something, your points is then already set. It doesn't walk back the whole stack to examine all possible transformable objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comments, random values in reprex represent remote sensing data, so perhaps use `SpatRaster` and `tidyterra::geom_spatraster`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rnaturalearth)

library(terra)
library(tidyterra)

set.seed(123)
df <- coords |> 
  mutate(value = runif(length(coords$x), 0, 100))

# get the coastline data as sf
coastlines_sf = ne_coastline(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")   

# create SpatRaster 
random_raster <- rast(df, crs = "WGS84")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = coastlines_sf, linewidth = .2) +
  geom_spatraster(data = random_raster) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(na.value = "transparent") +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could make your dataframe a spatial dataframe (class `sf`):

```
df <- df |> 
         st_as_sf(coords = c('x', 'y'),
                  crs = 4326 ## EPSG-Code for WGS84 coordinates
                  )
```

... after which you can use `geom_sf` and color instead of fill for aesthetics:

```
  ggplot(df) +
     geom_sf(aes(color = value)) +
     scale_color_viridis_c() +
     geom_sf(data = coastlines_sf) +
     coord_sf(crs = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ")
```

(note that your example data has no column "value")

Comment: I show on the first part of the code how I add a new column value. Did it not work for you as I thought it would? :)

Comment: This approach adds points instead of raster/tiles. Since my data is a remote sensing image, it only makes sense to plot it using either `geom_raster` or `geom_tile` :(